# adjusting resizable bar width of listgrid

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

In my ui there is a listgrid for which i set size 500

```
dataGrid=new ListGrid();
dataGrid.setWidth(500);
```

I want to use resizable bar for listgrid
`dataGrid.setShowResizeBar(true);`

but default width for resizable bar is >300 which makes my ui not good looking.

Is there any way to set resizable bar width exact to 500 or any size?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your UI looks so it is hard to judge, but I would prefer using [setCanDragResize(Boolean canDragResize)](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setCanDragResize%28%29) and defining the resizing directions with setResizeFrom(String... resizeFrom).

See [the showcase example](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#effects_dd_resize).
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default width for any resizable column in a ListGrid using ListGridField.setWidth() as follows:

```
// first create the grid and set columns to be resizable
dataGrid=new ListGrid();
dataGrid.setWidth(500);
dataGrid.setShowResizeBar(true);
dataGrid.setCanDragResize(true);

// set each column to the initial width you want for that column

ListGridField myColumn= new ListGridField("myColumn", "My Column");
myColumn.setWidth(400);  // default to 400 pixels wide

ListGridField myAnotherColumn= new ListGridField("myAnotherColumn", "Another Column");
myAnotherColumn.setWidth(300);  // default to 300 pixels wide


dataGrid.setFields(myColumn, myAnotherColumn);
```